# Relationship between model complexity (depth) and dataset size

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, training, deep-neural-networks

I'm new to deep learning. I was wondering what's the relationship between a deep model complexity (e.g. total number of parameters, or depth) and the dataset size?

Assuming I want to do a binary classification with 10K data for a problem like fire detection. How should I know what complexity I should go for?

Comment: In general, this is may not be an easy question to answer. The branch of artificial intelligence that studies these issues is called _computational_ (and _statistical) learning theory_. See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/75327/20691. I will eventually try to answer this question, but I don't know when.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah try to write something so i can give u some credit.

Comment: A recent question (https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39176/why-are-neural-networks-so-data-hungry) seems related to this one.