# Why are neural networks so data hungry?

Tags: neural-networks

Stephen Wolfram published an interesting long [post on machine learning](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/02/what-is-chatgpt-doing-and-why-does-it-work/) this week.

He illustrates a function approximation application with the following target function, piecewise flat with three regions.

[image]

I understand one can describe such a function with five parameters, the three constant levels (initially low, high in the middle and mid on the right) and the two discontinuity points.

As a network architecture, the following picture is given.

[image]

If my count is right, there are 19 weights (4+12+3 arrows) and 8 biases (count of all neurons but the input one, 4+3+1), totalling 27 parameters. The activation function is said to be ReLU for all neurons.

With this frame, we have 27 parameters in the model to estimate a 5 parameter function.

The following image illustrates how the model fits the function as the number of examples grows.

[image]

From 10 thousand examples to 10 milion examples. The magnitude of data required is much higher than the complexity of the target function and the approximating network.

> How should this (dis)proportion of data to problem parameters be understood?

Comment: Any number of factors can affect the data requirement. For example, some pairs of loss and activation functions, [such as cross-entropy logistic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_loss_function_and_logistic_regression), are unusually good at keeping the learning rate approximately constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example or sample is basically a pair of data $(x_i, y_i)$ with $x_i$ randomly picked from x axis and $y_i$ from the piecewise function. As you can see, it doesn't provide a lot information to calculating the weighting factors. By 10,000,000 randomly samples, one may capture the turning points. But if it is not randomly sampled, I would guess the number of sample can be less. The process is different from calculating model parameters from the piecewise function parameter as the neural net doesn't know it is a piecewise function as a priori. The function it expects is a general function, which can be very complex.

Comment: Yes! My mistake, plugging that a priori information that the network must learn on its own. Nice experiment to code, checking whether uniform sampling reduces the data size needed.